# I keep getting Thread 1 : Signal SIGABRT; Is there a way to view all IBOutlets in a project?

Tags: ios, swift

Every time I run my app I am now getting Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT in the AppDelegate.Swift file. All I did was switch some outlets around and delete a few. I'm thinking that's where it went wrong. So I ask if there is any way to view/edit ALL IBOutlets in a project in one window?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: If you are still in the beginning/inception phase of your project, would you be willing to post the code up on github.com/bitbucket.com so we can take a look?

Comment: Usually the error message in the console says "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key x", where `x` is the outlet it's looking for but not finding. Are you not getting any error on your console?

Answer (score 1):

Either you can right click on the view controller and see all IBOutlets or click on View controller and click on "Show the connection inspector" button under show Utilities.
Mostly you deleted IBOutlet from ViewController.swift but missed to delete the IBOutlet from ViewController in UI.